# Annotations loaded from plist not showing

Tags: ios, mkmapview, plist

This is the first time I am using a plist. I have been browsing around and I can't find any other help.

I have the code below in my `viewDidLoad`. How come my annotations are not showing?

```
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
mapView.delegate=self;


NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StationAddress" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"GasStation"];
NSLog(@" MapView is %@",mapView);
NSLog(@"anns is: %@", anns);


for(int i = 0; i < [anns count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"read2");

    double realLatitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
    NSLog(@" double lat value is %f",realLatitude);
    double realLongitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
    NSLog(@" double lot value is %f",realLatitude);

    NSLog(@"read3");



    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
    myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);

    myAnnotation.title = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];


    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
    [myAnnotation release];
```

EDIT MyAnnotation.h

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {

CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
NSString*               title;
NSString*               subtitle;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               title;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               subtitle;
```

MyAnnotation.m

```
@implementation MyAnnotation

@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize coordinate;
```

Hard Code for annotations, (this is inside viewdidload)

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

CLLocation *userLoc = mapView.userLocation.location;
CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLoc.coordinate;


NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",userCoordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",userCoordinate.longitude);

mapView.delegate=self;

NSMutableArray* annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

MKPointAnnotation *annot1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot1.title = @"TItle1"; 
annot1.subtitle=@"Address of title"; 
annot1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.946114, 120.792778); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot1];
```

and I did this for 3000 of them, but they ran slow, so I am trying to find a better way

Comment: How many annotations does the first NSLog show?  Try logging the lat and long values to make sure they're correct.  Make sure `mapView` is not nil.  Also, `[MyAnnotation release];` should be `[myAnnotation release];`.

Comment: Sorry Maybe I am too newbie to understand some part of what you are asking, but This is what it come out from the first NSlog:         {
        Address = "\U5f70\U5316\U7e23\U798f\U8208\U9109\U6cbf\U6d77\U8def\U56db\U6bb5256\U865f";
        Latitude = "24.035067";
        Longitude = "120.419800";
        Name = "\U53f0\U5851\U77f3\U6cb9";
    }
and it has about 2000+ of them. When I hardcode it, it shows perfectly fine, but once i use this plist, it disapper. mapView is sure not nil, and I did change My to my. THank you for helping and look forward for your additional helps. THanks!

Comment: Or do you recommend some other to do it? Thanks you very much. @Anna Karenina

Comment: While testing, just put 3 annotations in the plist.  After the `addAnnotation` line, put this: `NSLog(@"mapView.annotCount=%d, myAnnotation.coordinate=%f,%f", mapView.annotations.count, myAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, myAnnotation.coordinate.longitude);` and see what it prints.

Comment: Temporarily change `MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];` to `MKPointAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];` and then add that NSLog.  What happens?

Comment: it shows all 3 annotations [3940:207] mapView.annotCount=3, myAnnotation.coordinate=24.035067,120.419800   And the annotations are still not showing up at all. What is wrong?     @AnnaKarenina

Comment: And When I put all the annotations in and run it, it says receive memory warning and it takes about 14 seconds to finish loading it. After loading it, THe map didnt show up at all. @AnnaKarenina

Comment: If you have implemented the viewForAnnotation delegate method, please add that code to the question.

Comment: I don't have ViewforAnnotation, but I have the MyAnnotation.h and .m and let me post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Change:

```
     float realLatitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
```

To this:

```
     double realLatitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
     NSLog(@" double lat value is %f",realLatitude);
```

(do longitude also).

Also hint:  check for your annotations in the southern Atlantic Ocean, south west of Equatorial Guinea - that's where Lat/Lon of {0,0} is, and if your data isn't converting correctly, that's where your annotations might be.

Comment: I input them in, but The are not in 0,0 either. Maybe you can advice me some other ways to work it out?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, before your loop, add `NSLog(@" MapView is %@",mapview);` and see what you get.

Comment: MapView is <MKMapView: 0x192700; frame = (0 91; 320 369); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x192740>>

Comment: It's very odd since When I hard code it, it works fine, but once i switch to plist, it doesn't load at all

Comment: Have you tried using CLLocationCoordinate2DMake inside your for loop?

Comment: No I haven't really try coz I don't know how that work. Whenever I tried annot.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@"Latitude", @"Longitude"); It keeps saying I didn't define Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: In the code I posted in this answer, it shows how to get a value for realLatitude.  Do the same for realLongitude, and then do this:  `annot.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);`

Comment: I did what you said and please see my repost of the question on all the way to the top regard to the change I made with your help. The annotations are still not showing. I wonder why. Or Am i using the wrong code or wrong way? or is there a better way to load all 3000 dots faster without doing plist? Thanks in advance @Rayfleck

Comment: From the code you've posted, I can't find anything wrong.  As for the 3000, I have to wonder if the user will be able to use all 3000 in a meaningful way.  Is there a more relevant subset you can show?

Comment: Subset, do you mean it eg like by city? if so, can you give me some help on that?   Yeah the code is perfectly fine but slow, and that is why i was trying to do plist.

Comment: When I am only hardcoding few hundred dots, it works perfectly fine, but when I put in all 3000, it gets very slow sometime shows memory leak. can you give me a hand on this?

Comment: Where is are the 3000 dots' data stored when you're not using a plist?

Comment: just under view did load, and when the dots are only few hundred, it load fast, but not when there are 3000. It take forever even to compile the file.

Comment: Would you be willing to zip up the project and email it to me?  I will take a look and see if I can help you.  rayflection@gmail.com

Comment: wow Damn, While I was testing it out and it works!!! stupid reason. Coz I forgot to change my image name lol to the right name. But Thanks a lot!!!. And do you know how to make beginning lauch faster?